# What's this plant with fragrant leaves

Tags: identification, houseplants

This plant has very thin and fragile stems. It has very good smelling leaves. No flowers. Is there any way i can propagate it?
  [image]

Comment: It's not Thyme - don't eat it or use it in cooking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's Helichrysum petiolare, common  name liquorice plant; note that it is not edible, despite the common name. In the UK, this is a seasonal, frost tender plant used for decorative purposes in pots and tubs with summer bedding, but in other, warmer parts of the world, it is a short lived perennial or sub shrub. It usually flowers in its second year and may seed itself, otherwise, you can take cuttings, 4-6 inches long, with soft growth at the tip and woodier stems at the base - full instructions here https://living.thebump.com/propagation-helichrysum-petiolare-6685.html

For an image and general information on this plant, see here https://kumbulanursery.co.za/plants/helichrysum-petiolare

Comment: I think it looks like marjoram. What do you say? I saw pictures of it on google and the leaf pattern and smell in the description resembles a lot like my plant.

Comment: Marjoram/oregano doesn't have fuzzy (or furry) leaves like the ones in your image...

Answer (score 2):

You can simply propogate it by taking a cutting and putting that into a cup of water until roots are showing which from there you can transplant into some soil. A cutting 12" long, you'd remove the bottom 6 inches of foliage. Place the cutting into some water and in a warm sunny area. If you have aloe plants around too you should cut a few inches of a leaf, open it and scrap the inside of the aloe leaves into the water and that will help with root production. Sea salt ground into the water is helpful aswell.